# Adicionar link a imagem pelo arquivo *.CSS

Tags: css, imagem, link

Possuo um arquivo `*.css` que determinei a posição e tamanho da imagem que possuo em meu cabeçalho, é possível adicionar um `hyperlink` a essa imagem no próprio arquivo `*.css` e depois quando eu atribuir a essa imagem esse id do arquivo `*.css` ela já pegue o link também?

Comment: Não, nem faz sentido fazer isso. Qual seria o propósito?

Comment: Eu estou programando em uma ferramenta onde eu consigo selecionar meu arquivo `*.css` apenas não consigo colocar a tag `<img src="">` para selecionar a imagem quero colocar como ponto para acessar o link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No CSS não há propriedade que possa manipular o arquivo de imagem do elemento **img**. Se essa for realmente a necessidade sugiro você trocar pelo elemento **div** e especificar a imagem no **CSS**

Exemplo:

CSS:

```
#div_img {
  background-image:url('http://www.sitedaimagem.com/img/header.png'); /* url */
  width:396px; /* largura */
  height:153px; /* altura */
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="div_img"></div>
```

**1# Editada:**

Via CSS não é possível manipular o link, ou você defini direto no **HTML** ou no **JavaScript**

**2# Editada:**

Novo exemplo utilizando JQuery:
CSS:

```
#div_img {
  background-image:url('http://www.sitedaimagem.com/img/header.png'); /* url */
  width:396px; /* largura */
  height:153px; /* altura */
}
```

HTML:

```
<a id="div_link" href="http://www.uol.com.br"><div id="div_img"></div></a>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#div_link').attr('href','http://www.google.com');
})
```

Comment: Daí você pode atribuir várias propriedades no **CSS** para deixar o elemento **div** mais ou menos igual ao **img**

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Carlos Andrade, eu testei isso e não consegui, adicionei a linha:` background-image:url('http://www.google.com');` e depois chamei no HTML minha div porém ao clicar na imagem não fui redirecionado

Comment: Em `background-image:url('url_completo_da_imagem');` você deve especificar o endereço completo da imagem.

Comment: Ah, me desculpas, eu interpretei errada a pergunta. Vou fazer a edição e você pode desfazer o seu voto.

Comment: Aguardo sua resposta atualizada então +1

Comment: Desculpas mais uma vez, eu tinha entendido a **url** da imagem e não o **hyperlink**

Comment: tu poderia colocar um exemplo em Javascript para que eu veja se não resolve meu problema?

Comment: Sim, vou fazer a edição novamente.

Comment: Ótimo. Só tenho a acrescentar que se preferir não fazer por `background-image` você pode também fazer por `content` em um `::before`.